# The Omission of an Object Before a Clause

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

In the sentence `Find where I parked my car` the object of this sentecne seems to be:

`Find (the place) where I parked my car.`

Can anyone tell me in this sentence why the object, the place, is omittable?
Is the missing word （the place）is the main object?
Does the part "I parked my car" count as a modifier for the omitted object?

Comment: "Where I parked my car" is best analysed as a noun phrase in a 'fused’ relative construction in which "where" functions simultaneously as head of the noun phrase and prenuclear element in the relative clause. It has a paraphrase containing noun + integrated relative: “Find the place where I parked my car”. The prenuclear element is interpreted as object of "find".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No words are missing or implied. **where I parked my car** is what traditional grammars call a *noun clause*.

A *noun clause* normally contains a subject, verb, and any required objects or complements. It is normally introduced by **that** or one of the so-called "question words"—in this case, **where**.

A *noun clause* can be used in most places where a simple noun can be used. Here, the entire clause is being used as the object of **find**.

Comment: It's actually a noun phrase, not a clause, in a fused relative construction.

Comment: BillJ has a rather unconventional approach to grammar. According to section 33 of the Oxford Guide to English Grammar (John Eastwood, 1994) it's a noun clause.

Comment: Yes, my reference to "traditional grammars" was in anticipation of BillJ